# Define a function outside a class template for pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I want to define a member function for only pointers template parameters and for the rest of parameters types in another way. I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class W>
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

template<class T, class W> void A<T*, W*>::foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
int main(){  }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ff2f89c7d12c94d)**

It's not clear why it's not working. I put pointers template arguments in the same order they were specified in the template declaration. Actually `N4296::14.5.1/3 [temp.class]`:

> The template argument list following the class template name in the
>   member definition shall name the parameters in the same order as the
>   one used in the template parameter list of the member.

So why is the code not working? I put the parameters in the same order.

Comment: Try `... void A<T, W>::foo() { ...` instead, i.e. drop the asterisks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Dropping the asterisks defines `foo` for any `T`, `W`, not only for pointers.

Comment: Ah, so you want *specialization* of the function? However, you can't specialize only a single member function, you have to specialize the whole structure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok, I got that. Now I'd like to understand why it's so in a formal way. Couldn't you get a reference?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg BTW, why does the following code work fine [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c26f06b08fbbdd8d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the *entire struct* as a partial specialization, you can't just pick and choose individual members to specialize

[temp.class.spec]

> 1 [...] A partial specialization shall be declared before the ﬁrst use of a class template specialization that would make use of the partial specialization as the result of an implicit or explicit instantiation in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class W>
struct A
{
  void foo();
};

template<class T, class W>
struct A<T*, W*>
{
  void foo();
};

template<class T, class W> void A<T*, W*>::foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

int main() {}
```